# jQuery - Change CSS of one div that shares its class with other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change the CSS of a single DIV that shares its class with other divs.

I have been trying looking around for a solution but nothing seems to work.

I am trying using the code below without results:

```
$(".singleOffer").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().find(".offerSocial").css({transform: "translateY(0%)", opacity: "1" });
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="pattern" class="pattern">
  <ul class="g">

<li class="singleOffer">
      <img class="offerImg" src="<?php echo $file ?>" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
          <a class="previewLink" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $file ?>" >DOWNLOAD</a>
          <label class="shareLabel">Share on</label>
          <div class="share-buttons">
              <button class="fbShare" type="button" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $file ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); return false;">Facebook</button>
              <button class="twShare" type="button" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $file ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); return false;">Twitter</button>
          </div>
      <div>
</li>

<li class="singleOffer">
      <img class="offerImg" src="<?php echo $file ?>" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
          <a class="previewLink" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $file ?>" >DOWNLOAD</a>
          <label class="shareLabel">Share on</label>
          <div class="share-buttons">
              <button class="fbShare" type="button" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $file ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); return false;">Facebook</button>
              <button class="twShare" type="button" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $file ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); return false;">Twitter</button>
          </div>
      <div>
</li>

.....

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: didn't get the question, could you elaborate. You want the other .offerSocial  on clicking current .singleOffer with .offerSocial as child??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.offerSocial` is already a child of `.singleOffer`, so you want to remove the `.parent()` selector so you don't get ALL of the `.offerSocial` elements, and only the element that's associated with that specific `.singleOffer` element.

```
$(".singleOffer").click(function(){
    $(".offerSocial").css({ opacity: "0" });
    $(this).find(".offerSocial").css({transform: "translateY(0%)", opacity: "1" });
});
```

Comment: Thanks... did not think off it.. Is there a way to take to a normal state the authorise when one is clicked?

Comment: @SNos You're welcome! What do you mean by "take to a normal state the authorize"?

Comment: I mean right now if I click the css stays on. I want that the old div clicked opacity goes back to 0 when a new is clicked

Answer (score 1):

your html is something like this

```
 <ul class="g">

<li class="singleOffer">
      <img class="offerImg" src="<?php echo $file ?>" alt="Product Name" />
      <div class="offerSocial">
          <a class="previewLink" target="_blank" href="<?php echo $file ?>" >DOWNLOAD</a>
          <label class="shareLabel">Share on</label>
          <div class="share-buttons">
              <button class="fbShare" type="button" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $file ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); return false;">Facebook</button>
              <button class="twShare" type="button" onclick="window.open('<?php echo $file ?>', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=500'); return false;">Twitter</button>
          </div>
      <div>
</li>

...
</ul>
```

your js function fires on click of element with class `singleOffer`. It then gets to its parent that is `ul` and then tries to find elements with class `offerSocial` from its children. So it will find all the elements under the `ul` and apply your transformation there.

So all you should do to make the effect to just this div is remove the `parent()` function from your js

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want but I didn't understand why did you used parent. Remove the parent function.

```
$(".singleOffer").click(function(){
  $(this).find(".offerSocial").css({transform: "translateY(0%)", opacity: "1"});
});
```